# Google OAuth: "Couldn't sign you in. This browser or app may not be secure."

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

Our application uses Google OAuth to access GDrive and GMail APIs. Recently we noticed that during Google authorization some users get next message: "Couldn't sign you in. This browser or app may not be secure." etc. So the questions is:
What can be reasons of this? 
What can be done to fix this issue?
Is there any kind of Google Support for this kind of issues?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Actually Google blocks login from embedded browser frameworks in an effort to prevent man-in-the-middle (MitM) phishing attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when launching my app using Visual Studio.

For me it was related to Script Debugging (Enabled). I disabled Script Debugging and it worked.